# Automatically formatting statement on semicolon on getter, despite setting being off

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper, resharper-2018

When I type semicolon after `34` in this getter

[image: Before typing semicolon]

The getter is collapsed to a oneliner (I have no clue which setting does that)

[image]

but automatic format on semicolon is turned off.

[image: Setting is off]

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. In resharper settings change

[image]

to

[image]

and restart Visual studio (you are not told to restart vs, but you have to)